# How can i view big images using Qt?

Tags: c++, image, qt, itk, libtiff

I am trying to view big image (10 GB) using Qt and C++ but it didn't work because of limitation of memory on PC.

I have found that Big Tiff of [libtiff](http://bigtiff.org/#Introduction) library will be useful so want to write this viewer, can anyone tell me how can I implement big image viewer using Qt?

Comment: Question is too broad IMO, but as long as you have uncompressed data and you know the format, you can easily calculate the data ranges you need to load only a portion of the whole image.

Comment: You implement it by writing it yourself. Nobody will write it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I work in medical imaging (was actually involved in the creation of [one implementation of] BigTIFF) and... well, you simply don't do it this way.  Once you pass the "too large to load up completely in memory" threshold you need a less naive viewing strategy. For instance, TIFF's let you load portions of the image whenever you like, so you would load the current FOV and perhaps prefetch some tiles around it (not all TIFF's are tiled of course, but the strategy remains the same.)

When the user pans, do the same once again.  If you support zooming, you would likely also want to store the image in pyramid layers, i.e., the base image scaled down to multiple different magnifications.  This way you don't have to do all scaling in software or, when you need to interpolate, you can save yourself some time and memory by interpolating between levels surrounding the target magnification.

Essentially, you just need to be smart about how you store and fetch these images and, consequently, that requires a lot more work to get right.  Think "Google Maps", not "MSPaint".

Comment: if i want to edit a part in this image what should i use ? what's your opinion to do something like that in Big Images?

Comment: @AlyOsama: Well you can certainly just write the tile/strip/view/whatever back to the original image.  Exactly what kind of editing you are talking about will determine how you do it (for example, annotations may be best left in a separate file which your viewer loads up along with the image.  This way you don't lose the original data).

Comment: editing like change the value of some pixels or perform any transformation on a specific parts in the image ... etc.